# How can I add custom path for validators?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Zend Framework defaultly looks for validators only in this path:

```
Zend_Validate_: Zend/Validate/
```

How can I make it look also in, for example:

```
My_Validator_: My/Validator/
```

I can't find anything about this problem in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be

```
$element->addPrefixPath('My_Validator_', 'My/Validator', 'VALIDATE');
```

To do it at the form level, it should be:

```
$form->addElementPrefixPath('My_Validator_', 'My/Validator', 'VALIDATE');
```

Comment: A late +1 and a quick note that`Zend_Form::VALIDATE` gives an error `Undefined class constant 'VALIDATE'` Using the string `'VALIDATE'` works though. So I'm curious, why did you say that `Zend_Form::VALIDATE` was better?

Comment: In general, using the named constant - class based or global - is preferable to using the scalar values itself. For example, E_USER_WARNING is easier to understand than 512. Of course, it only applies when you get the constant name correct, which I obviously did not in my answer above. <embarassed smiley>. Removing the incorrect info. Sorry for the mis-information and thanks for the accept/upvote.